# Would a long pole help stablize a jet pack?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, flight-controls, experimental-aircraft

Jet packs are classically worn like a book-bag on the back. Would it be more stable if the exhaust ports were separated? Would the jet pack be easier to control if the turbines were at the ends of a long hollow pole that would also hold the fuel? Would a pole help stabilize hovering like it does a tight rope walker?

[image]

Comment: What has the image got to do with the question??

Comment: @Jamiec is this better?

Comment: Read about first [Goddard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_H._Goddard) experiments with rockets, he quickly discovered putting the exhaust above the structure don't improve stability

Comment: No. it doesn't. You've been warned before about irrelevant large images in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

First the reason why it could be absolutely terrible: a long pole is flexible, and you could run into awful oscillations. A long pole with two heavy masses at the end will have a very low resonance frequency, and probably also some interesting torsion effects.

The reason why you would want a separation is simple high school physics. You control your attitude with torque. A longer arm would mean a larger torque for the same thrust angle deflection. It would be a good solution if the thrust vectoring angles would be excessive otherwise.

From what I gather, the opposite is true. Minute adjustments cause a big change in attitude, and the system is already quite skitterish. The only use case for your system may be avoiding burnt legs.

Your idea of a hollow pole with fuel in it wouldn't be half bad though - it might help your jet pack operator balance, just like a rope walker. Just don't put jets on the end of the pole.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that much separation would help with control. See this article on actual "Iron Man" flying suit.

https://www.cbsnews.com/news/real-life-iron-man-suit-now-available-for-sale/